# Solution of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think it is a linear form of differential equation but i had problem integrating the rhs.

> Solve: $y'+x^2y= xe^x$

Comment: Please write down the solution as far as you got it. It looks very likely that the resulting integral can not be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve the DE using the series method
$$
y' = xe^x  - x^2 y;\;y\left( 0 \right) = 0
$$
Let $y = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^n } $ therefore we have $x^2 y = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^{n + 2} } $ and $
xe^x  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{x^{n + 1} }}{{n!}}} $
The DE equation can be written as
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {na_n x^{n - 1} }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{x^{n + 1} }}
{{n!}}}  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^{n + 2} } 
$$
As $y(0)=0$ we have $a_0$ and
$$a_1  + 2a_2 x + 3a_3 x^2  + 4a_4 x^3  + 5a_5 x^4  +  \ldots  = \\=x + x^2  + \frac{1}{2}x^3  + \frac{1}{6}x^4  + \frac{1}{{24}}x^5  \ldots  - a_0 x^2  - a_1 x^3  - a_2 x^4  - a_3 x^5  -  \ldots $$
Now setting equal the coefficients of the same powers of $x$ we get
$$
  a_1  = 0 \\
  2a_2  = 1 \to a_2  = \frac{1}{2}  \\
  3a_3  = 1 \to a_3  = \frac{1}{3} \\
  4a_4  = \frac{1}{2} \to a_4  = \frac{1}{8}  \\
  5a_5  = \frac{1}{6} - a_2  \to 5a_5  = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{2} \to a_5  =  - \frac{1}
{{15}} \\
\ldots\\
\ldots 
$$
Finally the solution can be written as
$$y=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^5}{15}+\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Very often you won't be able to find an analytic solution for an integral.

\begin{align*}
y'+x^2y &= x e^x \newline
(e^{x^3/3} y)' &= x e^{x+x^3/3} \newline
e^{x^3/3} y &= \int x e^{x+x^3/3} dx + C \newline
\end{align*}

Apparently, this $\int x e^{x+x^3/3} dx$  doesn't have an analytic solution, so I don't think you can get any better than that.

Comment: Yes i ended up in that only, i couldn't integrate the resultant intergral in rhs, is that okay, i mean will that be accepted or any other way to solve the integral.

Comment: You would need numerical methods to approximate its value. It just can't be analytically calculated. Another famous example of this case is $\int e^{x^2} dx$.